# Apt autoremove and issue

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel

After executing `sudo apt autoremove` everything seems okay, apart from this error:

```
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.10.0-20-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.10.0-20-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
```

How can I solve (how to install the aforementioned package)?

(Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit with the latest kernel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run `sudo apt install linux-headers-4.10.0-20-generic`

Comment: Now what to do? Should I execute again "sudo apt autoremove"?

Comment: I executed "sudo apt autoremove" and everything seems OK :)

Comment: Okey Keep going